# Constraining Movement of Agents to a Home Range in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm relatively new to NetLogo, and I'm working to model moose density in New Hampshire and its correlation to winter tick parasitism.

I'd like to program my moose agents to move randomly within a set home range (~5km2), that originates from the randomly chosen patch they first enter the model on.

I'm not really sure how to bound agents based on area, rather than just patch color... Any suggestions on how to do this would be most appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General stackoverflow tip: typically, stackoverflow encourages specific programming questions. So including the code you've actually tried so far is generally preferred.

Alright, on to your problem.

One really simple way to do this is, first, store the mooses' starting patch. Second, when the moose is moving around, check the distance to the starting patch. If the distance exceeds the starting amount, have the moose towards the starting patch. Here's some template code to give you ideas:

```
breed [ mooses moose ]

mooses-own [
  starting-patch
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ;; only using one moose as it's easier to see the behavior
  create-mooses 1 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set starting-patch patch-here
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask mooses [
    move
  ]
  tick
end

to move
  ;; If farther than 10 patches from starting patching, take a step towards starting patch, otherwise, move randomly
  ifelse distance starting-patch > 10 [
    face starting-patch
  ] [
    rt random 90
    lt random 90
  ]
  fd 1
end
```

Comment: Ah, sorry about that- noted for the future. Thanks so much- that solved my problem perfectly!